# Cannot POST / contact_process.php

Tags: php, html, css

i've tried to create this contact form and here is the HTML code:

```
 <section class="contact_info_area sec_pad bg_color">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 pr-0">
                    <div class="contact_info_item">
                        <h6 class="f_p f_size_20 t_color3 f_500 mb_20">Información de contacto</h6>
                        <p class="f_400 f_size_15"><span class="f_400 t_color3">Email:</span> <a href="mailto:admin@doupmedia.com">admin@doupmedia.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="contact_form">
                        <form action="contact_process.php" class="contact_form_box" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group text_box">
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Tu Nombre">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group text_box">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group text_box">
                                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group text_box">
                                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Teléfono">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group text_box">
                                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Página Web de la Empresa">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div>
```

```
                                <script>

                                $('.calendar').flatpickr({



                                   locale:"es",
                                   minDate: "today",

                                    "disable": [
    function(date) {
        // return true to disable
        return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

    }
],
"locale": {
    "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
}
                                })

                                </script>
                                </div>


                                <div>
                                 <label for="country">Tamaño de clientes aproximado</label>
                               <select id="clientes" name="country">
      <option value="australia">0 - 1k</option>
      <option value="canada">1k - 10k</option>
      <option value="usa">100k - 1M</option>
      <option value="usa">1M - 10M</option>
    </select>


                                      <label for="country">¿A qué hora va bien que te llamemos?</label>
                               <select id="clientes" name="country">
      <option value="australia">10:00 - 11:00</option>
      <option value="canada">11:00 - 12:00</option>
      <option value="usa">12:00 - 13:00</option>
      <option value="usa">13:00 - 14:00</option>
                                   <option value="usa">16:00 - 17:00</option>
                                   <option value="usa">17:00 - 18:00</option>
                                   <option value="usa">18:00 - 19:00</option>
                                   <option value="usa">19:00 - 20:00</option>
    </select>



                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group text_box">
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Deja tu mensaje..."></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-light">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" required="">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">He leído y acepto la <a href="" target="_blank">política de privacidad</a> y <a href="" target="_blank">protección de datos</a>.</label>
                              </div>
                   <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn_three" >Enviar Mensaje</button>

                        </form>

                        <div id="success">¡En breves nos pondremos en contacto contigo!</div>
                        <div id="error">Opps! Ha habido un error. Porfavor inténtelo de nuevo.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And when I try to edit the contact.php which is called contact_process.php it jumps a white page with thhat error: Cannot POST /  contact_process.php

If somebody knows the answer please help.

```
<?php

    $to = "runjiebusiness@gmail.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $name2 = $_REQUEST['name2'];
    $csubject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "You have a message from your Doup Media.";

    $logo = '';
    $link = '#';

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Bixcoin Master Mail</title></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
    $body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
    $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
    $body .= "</tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: please see answer below

Answer (score 0):

the `_REQUEST` variable is missing the field "`name2`". so the PHP script fails:

```
$name2 = $_REQUEST['name2'];
```

This means you need to add an input in your **form** for `name2` or remove this in your PHP script.